# Как включить в проекте сделанный уже package.json

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

Как включить в проекте сделанный уже package.json? Не могу разобраться.

1. `npm i gulp --save-dev`
2. `npm install`

Но ничего не происходит когда ввожу `gulp build`

Comment: Что значит "ничего не происходит"? сообщения какие-то появляются?

Comment: npm install достаточно чтобы поставить сразу все с готовым package

Comment: а gulpfile.js создан и все таски в нем прописаны?

Comment: gulp кажется глобально должен ставиться, `npm i -g gulp --save-dev`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev не обязательно ставить глобально. Можно поставить локально и прописать в PATH. Просто не понятно, то ли топикстартер в path не прописал (тогда бы у него консоль ругнулась при вызове gulp build), то ли конфиг не настроил, то ли хочет чего-то странного.